# Наложение Images в PictureBox

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Нужно в `PictureBox` наложить картинки одну на другую фон у них прозрачный по этому не должны перекрывать друг друга.

```
private: PictureBox^ TicketStatusPB = gcnew PictureBox();
private: Void TicketPresentIMG() {
    TicketStatusPB->Size = PrinterImage->Size;
    Image^ Ticket = gcnew Bitmap("PrinterStatusTicket.png");
    TicketStatusPB->Image = Ticket;
    PrinterImage->Controls->Add(TicketStatusPB);
    TicketStatusPB->BringToFront();
}

private: PictureBox^ OverTempPB = gcnew PictureBox();
private: Void TemperatureIMG() {

    OverTempPB->Size = PrinterImage->Size;

    Image^ TmpImg = gcnew Bitmap("PrinterStatusTemperature.png");
    OverTempPB->Image = TmpImg;
    PrinterImage->Controls->Add(OverTempPB);
    OverTempPB->BringToFront();
}
```

пробую так(вызываю методы по очереди), накладывается только последнее изображение. Как сделать наложение всех изображений с возможностью удалить в необходимый момент ?